# WIndows 10 ssh public key auth - server does not accept public key

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh, authentication, public-key

I'm having both client and server running Windows 10, and did the steps according to the following guidelines in both client and server(ssh-keygen, put pub key in server auth keys file...):
[Key-based Authentication for OpenSSH on Windows](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/may-2019/key-based-authentication-for-openssh-on-windows)

However, when I try to connect to the server I still asked to enter a password.
I can't really find a solution to this problem(even though searching for quite a while)

Here is the log from the public key auth part of the `ssh -vvv` command:

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: [*HERE WRITTEN RSA SHA256*] C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\maint/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```

Eventually, afterwards, I'm asked to enter a password

Comment: Is the target user member of the Administrators group? Have you looked for log files on the _server_ side?

Comment: The target user member is in the Administrators group.
Where can I find the log files?

Comment: Looked into the logs folder. Its empty

Comment: Set `SyslogFacility LOCAL0` and `LogLevel DEBUG` in "%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config" can enable logs for sshd (i.e., the server side). After modifying "sshd_config", you need to restart the "sshd" service. See [Troubleshooting Steps · PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH Wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Troubleshooting-Steps).